# use JdbcPagingItemReader return a List to ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-batch

1. I need use JdbcPagingItemReader in my project becaus pagination requirement is mandatory
2. how can I process those objects in bulk instead of processing one by one?
3. I want the reader to return a List of objects to processor instead of a single
4. I need JdbcPagingItemReader return a List of objects to processor

I don't know how to let it work, do you have any idea or examples?

here is my examples

```
@Bean
public Job batchUpdateInsiteGoodsJob(){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchUpdateInsiteGoodsJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(importGoodByExcelJobListener)
        .start(batchUpdateInsiteGoodsStep())
        .build();
}


@Bean
public Step batchUpdateInsiteGoodsStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("batchUpdateInsiteGoodsJob")
        .<Long,List<Goods>>chunk(10)
        .reader(batchUpdateInsiteGoodsReader())
        .processor(batchUpdateInsiteGoodsPorcessor)
        .writer(batchUpdateInsiteGoodsWriter)
        .faultTolerant().skip(Exception.class).skipLimit(100)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<Long> batchUpdateInsiteGoodsReader() {
    JdbcPagingItemReader<Long> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setFetchSize(100);

    reader.setRowMapper(new RowMapper<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Console.log("get id"+rs.getLong("id"));//here is the question,how can I make it return a List not a singe
            return rs.getLong("id");
        }
    });
    MySqlPagingQueryProvider provider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    provider.setSelectClause("id");
    provider.setFromClause("from tb_goods");
    provider.setWhereClause("status = 2 and is_remove = 0 and is_live = 1 and type = 1 and tb_commission_ration = 10");
    Map<String, Order> sort = new HashMap<>(1);
    sort.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
    provider.setSortKeys(sort);
    reader.setQueryProvider(provider);
    return reader;

@Service
public class BatchUpdateInsiteGoodsPorcessor implements ItemProcessor<Long,List<Goods>> {
@Override
public List<Goods> process(Long aLong) throws Exception {
    Console.log("get a Long"+aLong);
    return null;
}
```

}

how to make the reader return a List to ItemProcessor like

```
@Service
public class BatchUpdateInsiteGoodsPorcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<Long>,List<Goods>> {
@Override
public List<Goods> process(List<Long> aLong) throws Exception {
    Console.log("get a LongList"+aLong);
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, for the future, to improve the question, please include the relevant sample of the code that you have put together so far for us to see where you might be stuck.

Comment: You don't as that isn't how the reader and processor work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for examples, generally a good way to start is to read the [documentation of the class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) in question. In this case it directed me to docs.spring.io that helped to make a more directed search to

[the official guide with examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#JdbcPagingItemReader).

Comment: sorry,I've read the document but I don't find the answer to make JdbcPagingItemReader return a List of objects to processor instead of a single